# How to get all the input files from a form field in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a form where my form tag looks like this

```
<div class="page3-suggested-cat-wrap">
                <label for="3660" class="page3-suggested-cat-label">Upload File:</label>
                <input name="3660|449132" id="3660" value="questions(1).sql" type="file">
            </div>
```

So the name of the form is the name of question type in Database , Where there will be more than one file like this ,

I know in my controller ill have to do something like this

```
if (Input::hasFile('name of the file')) {
            dd('xxxx');
           //Do some stuff
        }
```

Since the name of the File field is dynamic how can I access in the controller side .

Before I just use to write the name of the file but I cant do that any more here

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can just use Input::all(). A input file or an input textfield are all the same. their both input fields but different features. Then you can do a print_r to see what inputs are shown then filter down based on the return you got to direct it towards file inputs

Comment: @SarmenB Let me try that

Comment: @SarmenB. Bro i can get the File name now but , When I applied the code `if (Input::hasFile($key))  dd('ddd') ` it doesnot find the file in the input array , But I can see the array with the file

Answer (score 4):

Hey this may help you.

```
echo "<pre>";
$file_array = \Input::file();
foreach ($file_array as $key => $value) {
   // Your dynamic field name
   echo $key;
   echo "<br/>";
   // File data
   print_r($value);
   echo "<br/>";
}
die();
```

Comment: bro the problem was in the form tag itself :)